# asp.net page life cycle explanation and examples

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I see that there is a lot of explanations of the page life cycle in ASP.NET, But I didn't find
 a document or blog that explain or demonstrate examples of recommendations for each life cycle (preinit,init,initcomplete and co). 
I know for example that it's recommend to bind data from DB to server controls on Page_Load event.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I always used this article as a reference point when i was learning: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/Asp-Net-page-life-cycle-events/

Answer (score 0):

I find [this article](http://fuchangmiao.blogspot.com/2007/11/aspnet-20-page-lifecycle.html) to be quite a good reference on the page life cycle in asp.net.

I usually follow the following broad guidelines for myself:

1. Init event - When databinding e.g. a DropDownList I do this on the control's Init event (if you do at later point the entire list will end up in viewstate unless you turn viewstate off).
2. Init event - When adding controls dynamically to control tree I do this in the Init event
3. Load event - setting control's values (e.g. loading field values from database and setting the input fields)